# JQuery - Multiplication inside new clone doesn't work

Tags: jquery, clone

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/waynebunch/jzqqLtff/)

I've created a function that clones when someone clicks a button.  Inside this div, there's a simple calculate function.  The calculate() function will work fine in the original div, but the clones don't perform the calculation.  I'm assuming it's because the clones aren't creating id's needed in my function.  Is there a way to keep my function working in the cloned divs?  I'm stumped and not really sure where to go from here.

---Also, I'm not sure why the calculate function isn't working at all in the Fiddle, it works fine everywhere else.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var target = $(this).closest(".groupcontainer"); // create var to clone
    target.clone(true, true).insertAfter(target); // clone and insert after
  });
});

function calculate() {
  var myBox1 = document.getElementById('input').value;
  var myBox2 = document.getElementById('input2').value;
  var grouptotal = document.getElementById('grouptotal');
  var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;
  grouptotal.value = myResult;


}
```

```css
/* begin the group container with all the elements*/

.groupcontainer {
  width: 650px;
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.behindgroup {
  background-color: black;
  width: 650px;
  height: 30px;
}
.group {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px;
  color: white;
  clear: both;
  display: inline-block;
}
.quantity {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}
.system {
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.total {
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.specs {
  float: left;
  width: 648px;
  min-height: 50px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  clear: both;
}
.specs table {
  width: 650px !important;
}
.specs table tr {
  background-color: white !important;
}
.specs table tr td {
  font-family: Arial !important;
  font-size: 9px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
  color: black !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.specs table tr td span {
  color: black !important;
  font-family: Arial !important;
  font-size: 9px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
}
.sa {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  clear: both;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.sapricing {
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  width: 24.6%;
  text-align: center;
}
#terms {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
.quantity1 {
  width: 5px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.systemprice {
  width: 113px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.grouptotal {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 120px;
}
.group_1 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 25px;
}
.gcLabel {
  width: 20%;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.input {
  width: 10%;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.input2 {
  width: 20%;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#quantity {
  width: 10%;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Begin the group sections-->


<div class="groupcontainer">
  <div class="behindgroup">
    <label class="gcLabel">Group:</label>
    <input class="group_1" type="text" />

    <label class="gcLabel">Quantity:</label>
    <input class="input" id="input" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />

    <label class="gcLabel">System Price:</label>
    <input class="input2" id="input2" type="text" oninput="calculate()" />

    <label class="gcLabel">Group Total:</label>
    <input class="grouptotal" id="grouptotal" />
  </div>


  <!--begin the specs here-->

  <div class="specs">


    <button>Clone groupcontainer and its children</button>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code should always go in your question first, with links to offsite resources an optional second. The system warned you about posting a link to jsFiddle.net without any actual code in your question, yet you chose to try and circumvent that warning by highlighting random bits of text as code. Please do as you were asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do your calculation differently. I did it with jQuery by having the listeners on the classes instead of the elements.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p26ad2n2/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var target = $(this).closest(".groupcontainer"); // create var to clone
    target.clone(true, true).insertAfter(target); // clone and insert after
  });

  $('.input').on('input', function() {
    $(this).parent().children('#grouptotal').val($(this).val() * $(this).parent().children('#input2').val());
  });

  $('.input2').on('input', function() {
    $(this).parent().children('#grouptotal').val($(this).val() * $(this).parent().children('#input').val());
  });

});
```

```css
/* begin the group container with all the elements*/

.groupcontainer {
  width: 650px;
  background-color: white;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.behindgroup {
  background-color: black;
  width: 650px;
  height: 30px;
}
.group {
  font-family: Arial;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px;
  color: white;
  clear: both;
  display: inline-block;
}
.quantity {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}
.system {
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.total {
  float: left;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.specs {
  float: left;
  width: 648px;
  min-height: 50px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  clear: both;
}
.specs table {
  width: 650px !important;
}
.specs table tr {
  background-color: white !important;
}
.specs table tr td {
  font-family: Arial !important;
  font-size: 9px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
  color: black !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.specs table tr td span {
  color: black !important;
  font-family: Arial !important;
  font-size: 9px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  margin: 0px !important;
}
.sa {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: black;
  clear: both;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.sapricing {
  background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  height: 20px;
  width: 24.6%;
  text-align: center;
}
#terms {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10px;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
.quantity1 {
  width: 5px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.systemprice {
  width: 113px;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.grouptotal {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 120px;
}
.group_1 {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 25px;
}
.gcLabel {
  width: 20%;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.input {
  width: 10%;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.input2 {
  width: 20%;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#quantity {
  width: 10%;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 12px;
}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Begin the group sections-->


<div class="groupcontainer">
  <div class="behindgroup">
    <label class="gcLabel">Group:</label>
    <input class="group_1" type="text" />

    <label class="gcLabel">Quantity:</label>
    <input class="input" id="input" type="text" />

    <label class="gcLabel">System Price:</label>
    <input class="input2" id="input2" type="text" />

    <label class="gcLabel">Group Total:</label>
    <input class="grouptotal" id="grouptotal" />
  </div>


  <!--begin the specs here-->

  <div class="specs">


    <button>Clone groupcontainer and its children</button>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome thank you!  Confusing to me, I'll need to take some time to figure your answer out haha

Comment: @WayneBunch I only edited the JavaScript and removed the `oninput` from the html. I essentially used jQuery instead of your calculate method.

Comment: Trying to figure out the `$(this).parent().children *`.  Is this used because of the cloning or would you do it that way even without the cloning?

Comment: @WayneBunch Yes, this is done because of the cloning, so that it only gets the elements that are within the same group.